# AWS Glue: passing additional Python modules to the job - ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, pyspark, aws-glue, modulenotfounderror

I'm trying to run a Glue job (version 4) to perform a simple data batch processing. I'm using additional python libraries that Glue environment doesn't provide with - [translate](https://pypi.org/project/translate/) and [langdetect](https://pypi.org/project/langdetect/). Additionally, regardless of the Glue env provides with 'nltk' package, when I try to import it I keep receiving the error that dependencies are not found (e.g. regex._regex, _sqlite3).

I tried a few solutions to achieve my goal:

1. using `--extra-py-files` where I specified path to s3 bucket where I uploaded either:

- `.zip` file that consists of translate and langdetect python packages
- just a directory for already unzipped packages
- packages itself in `.whl` format (along with its dependencies)

2. using `--additional-python-modules` where I specified path to s3 bucket where I uploaded:

- packages itself in `.whl` format (along with its dependencies)
- or just pinpoint which package has to be installed inside the glue env via `pip3`

3. using Docker

Additionally, I followed a few useful sources to overcome the issue of ModuleNotFoundError:

a) https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/glue-import-error-no-module-named/.

b) https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/glue-version2-external-python-libraries/

c) https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-python-libraries.html

Also, I tried to play with the Glue versions 4 and 3 but haven't had luck. It seems like a bug. All permissions to read s3 bucket is granted to the glue role. The Python script version is the same as the libraries I'm trying to install - Python 3. To give you more clues, I manage glue resources via Terraform.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Can you share the specific error you are facing?

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76994134/aws-cdk-glue-alpha-job-how-to-import-module-in-extrapythonfiles

Comment: Hi @Kangoor, have you solved this? There is a lack of documentation and I'd like to solve a similar problem and then document it here on SO

Answer (score 1):

The way I have been able to achieve this is in AWS Glue 4.0 is by taking the following steps:
Under the Job Details tab, scroll down to Advanced Properties and expand that section. Locate the Job parameters region and add a New Parameter. For key, enter the text below:
--additional-python-modules
For value, enter your package name as found in the pyp.org. Example:
PyMySQL==1.0.3,SQLAlchemy==2.0.19
or in your case:
langdetect==1.0.9,translate==3.6.1

For each package, use a comma to separate them.  This process is a lot easier than zipping packages and uploading to s3.