# AWS CDK glue-alpha Job: How to import module in `extraPythonFiles`?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I'm using AWS CDK to create a Glue Job. Following this documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-glue-alpha.PythonSparkJobExecutableProps.html) I found that it's possible to provide extra Python files to the job, which is useful to me because I want to import a module that I have as a python file.
As a note, I'm using the `@aws-cdk/aws-glue-alpha` library because it allows the definition of a job from a code asset.

This is my job definition in CDK:

```js
    new glueAlpha.Job(this, id + '-aggregate', {
      jobName: id + '-aggregate',
      executionClass: glueAlpha.ExecutionClass.FLEX,
      sparkUI: {
        enabled: true,
      },
      role: iam.Role.fromRoleName(this, id, 'service-role/AWSGlueServiceRole'),
      workerCount: 2,
      workerType: glueAlpha.WorkerType.G_1X,
      defaultArguments: {
        '--environment_tag': env_tag, 
        '--s3_bucket': dataBucket.bucketName,
      },
      executable: glueAlpha.JobExecutable.pythonEtl({
        glueVersion: glueAlpha.GlueVersion.V3_0,
        pythonVersion: glueAlpha.PythonVersion.THREE,
        script: glueAlpha.Code.fromAsset(glueSourceCode + '/data_quality.py'),
        extraPythonFiles: [glueAlpha.Code.fromAsset(sourceCode + '/my_module.py')],
      }),
    });
```

The deployment is successful, and I can see the file in two places:

- as an S3 file, from the job details in the GUI;
- as a temporary file in the Job filesystem, running the following from the script

```py
import sys
import os
for p in sys.path:
    try:
        print(p, ':', os.listdir(p))
    except BaseException as e:
        print(e)

localPyFilesDir = [d for d in sys.path if d.startswith('/tmp/localPyFiles')][0]

pyFile = os.listdir(localPyFilesDir)[0]

with open(localPyFilesDir + '/' + pyFile, 'r') as f:
    print(f.read())
```

The names for these files are randomly generated, for instance the temporary file is `/tmp/localPyFiles-c1f3490d-fc78-4c0f-9508-ab56cf172ba8/60c153050f78fd7e06e53a4326f4f7423c7ad2747e6f865ffd56d9ba57a002e2.py`.

---

My question is: how can I import this file as a python module from the script? I guess there is a way to do it without knowing the temporary path, because it looks very involved and it would surprise me that there is no easier way even to get the path to the file.